# Knowledge Tab not able to see in Production - giving error

Tags: knowledge, lightning-knowledge

User is not able to see Knowledge Tab. 
I have checked below settings, User is knowledge User also Knowledge One is enable on his profile. But Tab for Knowledge is set to Default Off. When I try to change it. It is giving me an below error. Can any one please help me. I am performing this activity in production. So bit worried before changing anything,

> Permission Manage All Related Contacts depends on permission(s): Read
>   All Accounts Permission Read All Related Contacts depends on
>   permission(s): Read All Accounts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue. As Error say - I have added Read All permission on Account Object and then tried to Change Knowledge tab settings to Default On and it worked. Then I reverted account obj related changes

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what is an error, can you please help me with the exact error.

Make sure the object settings in the profile.